# Attribute "empty" not working as expected with SimpleFramework

Tags: android, xml, simple-framework

So I was trying to set an empty attribute when an element has no value.

So my class looks like this:

```java
@Order(attributes = { "name" })
public class TypeNumber {
    @Attribute(required = false)
    protected String name;

    @Element(required = false)
    @Attribute(empty = "xsi:nil=\"true\"")
    protected BigDecimal value;

    //getter setter methods goes here  
}
```

In case of empty value I was expecting output:

```
<field name="some_name">
    <value xsi:nil="true"/>
 </field>
```

While the actual output is:

```
<field name="some_name"/>
```

Any idea why the empty attribute is not working as expected? 
Or am I doing it wrong ?

**Note:** I am using SimpleFramework XML with `VisitorStrategy`. So, can't use `AnnotationStrategy`. Also I have custom Visitor to read and write nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### You will need a custom Converter...

Right now your outputs are:
`<typeNumber name="original" value="10"/>`
and
`<typeNumber name="original_empty" value="xsi:nil=&quot;true&quot;"/>`

### So let's get started!

First thing you got to do is pass AnnotationStrategy to the constructor of your Persister:

`Serializer serializer = new Persister(new AnnotationStrategy());`

.. then create a custom Converter in your model:

```
@Root(name = "TypeNumberFixed")
@Order(attributes = {"name"})
@Convert(TypeNumberFixed.FixConverter.class)
class TypeNumberFixed {
    @Attribute(required = false)
    protected String name;

    @Element(required = false, name = "value")
    protected BigDecimal value;


    public static class FixConverter implements Converter<TypeNumberFixed> {

        @Override
        public TypeNumberFixed read(InputNode inputNode) throws Exception {
            //Implement your own deConverter
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void write(OutputNode node, TypeNumberFixed value) throws Exception {
            node.setAttribute("name",value.name);
            OutputNode valueNode = node.getChild("value");
            if (value.value != null) {
                valueNode.setValue(value.value.toPlainString());
            } else {
                valueNode.setAttribute("xsi:nil", "true");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will generate following output for empty/nonempty *values* respectively:

**typeNumberFixed.value = null**:

```
<TypeNumberFixed name="new_empty">
   <value xsi:nil="true"/>
</TypeNumberFixed>
```

**typeNumberFixed.value = 30**:

```
<TypeNumberFixed name="new">
   <value>30</value>
</TypeNumberFixed>
```

[Here's](https://github.com/fuho/SO41426251) the repo if you're interested.

Comment: We're having VisitorStrategy everywhere and accordingly we have written code. I can't use AnnotationStrategy Just for the sake of one variable. :(